# difference between curl and python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to access my firewall API.

and i got a good answer in curl with:

```
curl -k -i -u admin:xxxx -X POST https://10.0.0.2:9443/api/sonicos/auth 
#=> Ok
```

with requests, api said HTTP 406 
here is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
r = requests.post(
    'https://10.0.0.2:9443/api/sonicos/auth', 
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'xxxx'), 
    headers={'Content-type': 'Application/JSON'}, 
    verify=False
)
```

API documentation said: 406  Not acceptable
Mime-type in content-type not supported.

I try a lot of parameters without success.
Any idea to help me?

Thanx

Comment: Does the API docs says what kind of content-type it accepts?

Comment: Why are you sending an `application/json` content type?

Comment: With @moritzg. Especially since you aren't POSTing any data.

Comment: Henkq: uses two different content types for requests. Server: performs differently. Henkq: Pikachu face.

Comment: @Stargazer : API docs said mime-type accept application/json and text/plain

Comment: @moritzg : api reference said  empty body for method POST or GET. So do i need to have any data ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, and according to the RFC 2045, the content type should be lowercase. In your case, "'Content-type': 'application/json'"

Comment: This is correct and valuable, but doesn't actually answer the question. It should be a comment on the question. Especially since it's not clear why the OP is using that content type in the first place.

Comment: @sne4ky, put content-type in lower case doesnt slove the pb.
and whitout content-type headers. Il's the same.